# Debugging CutyCapt + Flash

Tags: flash, ubuntu, cutycapt

I have a system on Ubuntu 12.04 that uses xvfb, CutyCapt, and Adobe Flash to capture a screenshot of an HTML page with embedded Flash.  All packages are the Ubuntu 12.04 release packages (nothing custom compiled).

xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" cutycapt --url=http://www.270towin.com/2012_election_predictions.php?mapid=mFh --plugins=on --delay=10 --out=test.png

The setup works just fine for capturing Flash.  The problem I am having is that the Flash object makes some remote data calls and changes display state based on the remote data.  My screenshot captures the state of the Flash object at load time, but does not ever capture the visual changes after the remote data calls.

Using tcpdump I am able to see that the appropriate data calls are being made.  I have tried delaying CutyCapt by various intervals up to 90 seconds to see if it would capture the new state, no dice.

I appreciate any assistance in debugging this problem further, even if the answer is "go here".  I'm not too familiar with the Qt development world.

Comment: I saw that your are speaking about capturing Flash content using CutyCapt and I want to ask you : have you really got to do it ? If yes, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842154/cutycapt-dont-work-with-flash) may be you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware that cutycapt's `delay` parameter takes a millisecond value? Therefore, if you want to delay for 10 seconds, it should be `10000`, not `10`.

This would explain why you weren't seeing any state change, as the delay was too short.

Comment: Facepalm.

That appears to have been the issue.